# Show buttons instead of pin on map in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using `MKMapView` to show annotations on `MKMapView` but now I want to display custom annotations instead of default map pins.

How can I do this..?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show your codes?

Comment: I mean to say that, as we can show custom pin on the point of latitude and longitude on map. In the same way I want to show UIButton on the place of latitude and longitude on map.

Comment: Show some codes please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
        MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView 
                dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"pin"];
        if (annView == nil) {
            annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                          reuseIdentifier:@"pin"] autorelease];

            annView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);

            UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 28);
            pinButton.tag = 10;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinButtonTap:)];
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [pinButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];

            [annView addSubview:pinButton]; 
        }

        annView.annotation = annotation;

        UIButton *pb = (UIButton *)[annView viewWithTag:10];
        [pb setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        return annView;
}

- (void) handlePinButtonTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // Your tap action goes here
}
```

Comment: But my MapView is declared in UIView class and i am creating annotation from UIViewController class. Annotation are displaying fine but I can't add click event on annotations. How can I fire click event.

Comment: Creating button annotation using: UIButton *pinButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [pinButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_marker.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 25);
    [pinButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Use this [pinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pinButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; and implement your actions in the pinButtonClicked method.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this..?

Stop using `MKPinAnnotationView` and instead create your own subclass of [`MKAnnotationView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).